# Binding a new Dispatcher to a thread in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

I have a situation where I am showing a `Window` which acts as a splash screen. This window is created on a separate thread from the main ui thread and as such it is associated with its own `Dispatcher` (i.e. I end up with 2 Dispatchers the Main Ui dispatcher and the "Splash" `Dispatcher`).

When I close the splash window the `Dispatcher` associated with the splash window's thread shuts down (though the thread is still running, which is what I want); however, I would like to be able to show the splash window again at a later time on the same thread. The problem I face is the second time I try and do this the `Dispatcher` complains that it has been shut down.

**Is there a way to force a new `Dispatcher` to be associated with a thread which previously had a `Dispatcher` associated with it?**

**Or is there a way to cause the `Dispatcher` not to shutdown when the window is closed?**

I am aware I could solve this issue by creating a new thread, but I really would prefer not to do this. Ideally I want to have one dedicated thread which is responsible for out of band notifications like the splash and popup "toasters".

NOTE:
I've posted the relevant code at this gist: https://gist.github.com/DamianReeves/76771a031f05a8be042d

Comment: What happens if you call: `Dispatcher.Run()` on the 2nd thread after it was previously shutdown?

Comment: Also, it might help if you could include just the bare minimum code to repo your issue. This way we could verify that a solution works before posting an answer..

Comment: Thats precisely what I am doing and it throw an `InvalidOperationException` with the following description: Additional information: "Cannot perform requested operation because the Dispatcher shut down."

Comment: Added a gist with most of the relevant code: https://gist.github.com/DamianReeves/76771a031f05a8be042d

Comment: Have you read this? http://reedcopsey.com/2011/11/28/launching-a-wpf-window-in-a-separate-thread-part-1/  I've used it successfully in the past.

Comment: The issue mentioned is kind of the opposite of what I'm facing (my code shutsdown the dispatcher, his code  wasn't and he is forcing it). That being said, I'll take a closer look at how my use of the 'EventLoopScheduler` is affecting the behavior of the second thread.

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but have you tried Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher which should create a new Dispatcher for the calling thread. What I'm unsure of is whether a shutdown Dispatcher will be replaced...

Comment: I have, and it doesn't seem to be replaced

Comment: What about just hiding the window instead of closing it? You said you plan on showing it again later on anyways.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question:
Is there a way to force a new Dispatcher to be associated with a thread which previously had a Dispatcher associated with it?

"When a Dispatcher is created on a thread, it becomes the only Dispatcher that can be associated with the thread, even if the Dispatcher is shut down."

also

"If a Dispatcher is shut down, it cannot be restarted."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.threading.dispatcher
in the Remarks section.

Comment: Thanks for answering the first part of the question, the documentation is pretty clear.